# Having trouble making input (checkbox) follow CSS absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying adapt a floating button effect to my application and for some reason I cannot make the checkbox follow the absolute positioning rules I set up, only it's label moves around.

Here's the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/pklepa/pen/vYXerBq).

```
#menu-toggle 
    &:not(:checked) 
        & + label 
            &:hover 
                box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0784314) 0px 0px 12px 0px

            & + #menu 
                li 
                    opacity: 0 
                    position: absolute 
                    top: 0 
                    left: 0
                    pointer-events: none 
            
            #close
                display: none

    &:checked
        & + label 
            position: absolute 
            bottom: 14% 
            right: 6% 
            width: 200px 
            height: 150px 
            background-color: white 
            border-radius: 3px 
            box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.117647) 0px 0px 8px 0px
            transition: 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) 
            z-index: 1 

            #open 
                opacity: 0 
                pointer-events: none 

            #close 
                position: absolute 
                top: -32px 
                right: 10px 
                color: #5c94fc 
                font-size: 33px!important 
                border: 3px solid red
                opacity: 1
```

Notice that I added a border in the checkbox in order to better understand what is going on.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For correct positioning, add rule `line-height: inherit` to `#menu-toggle:checked + label #close`:

```
#menu-toggle:checked + label #close {
    ...
    line-height: inherit;
}
```

in sass:

```
#menu 
    position: absolute 
    padding: 0 
    bottom: 12% 
    right: 8% 
    width: 80px 
    height: 80px 
    border-radius: 50% 
    border: none 
    transition: 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) 
    z-index: 1

    line-height: inherit /*this it*/
```

Comment: Ok, although this didn't solve my problem right away - it led me to better understand my problem which is the fact that my #menu ul was positioned on top of the label with the close button and by manipulating its size I managed to get around the issue.

Comment: How did you fix it? And why not my decision?

Comment: Well, the inherited line-height didn't seem to have any effect on the main issue (the fact that the checkbox not clickable from the X). What I did was to lower the ```#menu-toggle:checked #menu``` width and reposition it within the label